# polynomials with integer coefficients part 2

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)=x^7+x^6+b_5x^5+...+b_1x+b_0$ and $q(x)=x^5+c_4x^4+...+c_1x^+c_0$ be polinomial with integer coefficients.Assume that p(i)=q(i) for integers i=1,2,..,6.Thus there exists a negative integer r such that p(r)=q(r).

Comment: Do you mean $q(x)=x^5+c_4\color{red}{x^4}+...+c_1x+c_0$?

Comment: Please give some context/attempts to this problem.This will help users to cater to your needs and will avoid possible downvotes/closing of question

Comment: Hint: $p(x)-q(x)=x^7+x^6+\cdots$ has six or seven real roots, and what do its roots add up to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\implies p(i)-q(i)=(i-1)(i-2)(i-3)(i-4)(i-5)(i-6)(i+s). s\in I^{+}$$
$7th$ degree polynomial equation $r(x)=p(x)-q(x)$ has integer coefficients, since it has 6 positive integer roots (1 to 6). So its 7th rood needs to be a negative integer and further as sum of the roots of $r(x)=0$ is $-1$, so the 7th root is $-22 (s=22).$